# Will any buoyant force act on the block when it settles at the bottom?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering

Consider a cylindrical container that is filled with water to the rim. Now, an iron block of Volume $V$ is dropped slowly into the container. The volume of the water that spills out will also be $V$, as that is the volume that is now occupied by the block, in water. Iron block eventually settles at the bottom.

When we draw a Free body diagram of the block at the bottom, **will there be a buoyant force acting** or will the only forces acting be normal reaction and weight?

---

I feel yes buoyant force will be acting. But if that is the case, the equation of equilibrium would be,

$$N+F_B=W$$
$$W=N+\rho Vg$$

and since $N$ would be an unknown, how will I be able to determine the weight of the block, if suppose I'm asked to? (just by knowing $V$)

---

The backstory to this question: I was about to sell a wheelchair to someone and over the phone he happened to ask me the weight of it, which I didn't know. I do not have any weighing machines, so I thought what if I had a large tank of water, would I've been able to determine the wheelchair's weight? I thought of drawing the FBD of the chair and writing an equilibrium equation when it reached the bottom, but I would have a $N$ how would I determine that?

Comment: weigh yourself using scales. Then weigh yourself carrying the wheelchair. Then a subtraction.

Comment: that's an XY question ... asking about your solution to `how to weigh an object without using scales?`

Comment: yes buoyant forces still act on the submerged block, but no, this will help you exactly zero in weihging the block.

Comment: @TigerGuy because it's a body force right? That's why it still acts when the block will be at the bottom. Thanks